# php // what should i do to display all courses?

Tags: php

i need to display all courses at once

in my code only display one course what should i do to fix it ? 
when i click delete  it reload page and display next courses 
my code ::

```
$course = $conn->query("select * from student_course where student_id = $id ") ;
if($course->num_rows > 0) { 
    ?> 
    <table class="table" >
    <tr> 
        <thead>
            <th> courseName </th>
            <th> courseID </th>
            <th> teacher </th>
            <th> DELETE </th>
        </thead> </tr>
    <?php 

while ($Scourse = $course->fetch_assoc()){ 
    $cid=$Scourse['course_id'];
    $tid=$Scourse['teacher_id']; 
        $teacher = $conn->query("select * from teacher where id = $tid ") ;
        if($teacher->num_rows > 0) {


        while($teacherC=$teacher->fetch_assoc()){

        $course = $conn->query("select * from course where id = '$cid' ") ;
        if($course->num_rows>0){
        while($Ncourse=$course->fetch_assoc()){ ;
 ?>  
 <tr> <td><?php echo $Ncourse['name']; ?> </td>
 <td><?php echo $Scourse['course_id']; ?> </td>
 <td> <?php echo $teacherC['name']; ?> </td>
 <td><form method="post"><button type="submit" name="<?php echo $cid ?>"> Delete </button></form> </td></tr>

<?PHP 

    if (isset($_POST["$cid"])){

    $dcourse = $conn->query("delete from student_course where course_id = '$cid' and 
        student_id=$id ") ;


    header("location:scourse.php");

}
}
} 
}
}
}
}

</table>
```

i try to delete teacher and course query it work as i need

Comment: Instead of nesting three loops, you can `JOIN` the queries and just run one.

Comment: You have a semicolon at the end of `while($Ncourse=$course->fetch_assoc()){ ;`, which is causing issues for you. Therefor, I'm voting to close the question as a typo.

Comment: i remove  a semicolon and nothing change

Comment: i  join the queries and it run as i need  thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You're handling associate arrays improperly.
You will need a foreach loop to loop through each row in the associate array.

Example:

```
foreach($Scourse as $x) {
    echo $x['name'];
    echo $x['course_id'];
}
```

See Loop through Associate Arrays here:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp

Edit: See @Qirel comments

Comment: OP is looping correctly, see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: @Qirel He is to GET the information, but he's not looping in his echo, which is causing him to only display the first course in the list. There's nothing wrong with his actual data, it's the display of the data that is messing up. He's not looping his display table. His while loop cuts off right before he echos the data.

Comment: The issue is actually that `while($Ncourse=$course->fetch_assoc()){ ;` has a semicolon at the end, which terminates the loop after the first round. But your example of using a foreach-loop won't work unless OP fetches every row into that variable *before* the loop. So the solution isn't to use a foreach-loop, but to remove that semicolon.

Comment: @Qirel You're right. I thought that's what he was attempting to do because he terminated his while loop early, but your answer is probably his original thought.

Comment: Your answer is the correct way to loop an array, yes - but when fetching rows from a database, OPs way is how you normally do it ;-) That being said, these 3 queries can probably be made into a single query using `JOIN`.